# cannot update an array of elements via a 2d iteration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of object, the first array (printerChart, around 80 elements) is made of the following type of objects:

```
[{
    printerBrand: 'Mutoh',
    printerModel: 'VJ 1204G',
    headsBrand: 'Epson',
    headType: '',
    compatibilty: [
      'EDX',
      'DT8',
      'DT8-Pro',
      'ECH',
    ],
  },
   ....
]
```

The second array (items, around 500 elements) is made of the following type of objects:

```
[
        {
            "customData": {
                "brand": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "content": "hp"
                    },
                    "key": "brand"
                },
                "printer": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "content": "c4280"
                    },
                    "key": "printer"
                }
            },
            "name": "DT8 XLXL",
            "image": {
                "id": "zLaDHrgbarhFSnXAK",
                "url": "https://xxxxxxx.net/images/xxxxxx.jpg"
            },
            "brandId": "xxxxx",
            "companyId": "xxxx",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-26T14:39:47.326Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-04-09T14:31:38.169Z",
            "points": 60,
            "id": "dq2Zezwm4nHr8FhEN"
        },
  ...
]
```

What I want to do is to iterate via the second array and, if the part of the name of an item (i.e. DT8) is included in an element of the array 'compatibility' of the first array, I would like to include a new properties to it from the element of the first array: printerBrand. I have tried but somehow the iteration doesn't take place correctly. This is what I tried:

```
items.forEach((item) => {
      printerChart.forEach((printer) => {
        if (printer.compatibilty.some(compatibleElem => (
          item.name.includes(compatibleElem)))) {
          item.printerBrand = printer.printerBrand;
        } else {
          item.printerBrand = '';
        }
      });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I changed it to a forEach...

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
items.items.forEach(...)
```

Shouldn't you be doing

```
items.forEach(...)
```

?

Comment: it was just a writing mistake, the problem still persists

Comment: Try using item.name.indexOf(compatibleElem) != -1 instead of using the "includes" method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to initialize `item.printerBrand` with an empty string and use a nested approach of `some` for getting a brand and to exit the loops, if found.

This prevents to get an empty string even if there is a brand to assign.

```
items.forEach((item) => {
    item.printerBrand = '';
    printerChart.some(printer => {
        if (printer.compatibilty.some(compatibleElem => item.name.includes(compatibleElem))) {
            item.printerBrand = printer.printerBrand;
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```